# Morse code in Passenger's Things You've Never Done

Tags: lyrics, meaning

Things You've Never Done by Passenger has some Morse code near the beginning and near the end. What does it say?

The Morse code is from 0:06 to 0:21 and 3:25 to 3:35 [I'm not confident that uploading the samples fits under "fair use".]

Comment: Would you mind posting a sound clip?  I can't hear any morse code, it just sounds like fingerstyle guitar.

Answer (score 2):

I experimented with the song in Audacity. I found that if I edit the 0:06 to 0:21 segment in this manner, I can separate the Morse pretty well. What's cool is you can actually read much of the morse visually.

- Filter with a high-pass filter at a cutoff frequency of 1600Hz and a rolloff of 48dB per octave
- Filter with a low-pass filter at a cutoff frequency of 1700Hz with a rolloff of 48dB per octave
- amplify
- Change the tempo from 30 to 15.

What I find is that I don't think the Morse code is a message.  Here's what I transcribed. (maybe you would transcribe it differently?)

```
-.... . -. .... . . -. .... . -. .... . -. .... . -. .... .

6 e n h e e n h e n h e n h e n h e
```

I think the Morse is chosen for its rhythmic effect.

The Morse at the end of the song doesn't separate nearly as well because of the heavier instrumentals at the time.

I made a video of the filtered music: https://youtu.be/O135Z8TxK0k [note: I had to replace the video, the first one had horrific clipping.]

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty well buried beneath the music so all I can pick out is "then he" which repeats a couple of times. There may be more to it but it's too hard to hear.